# laravel jetstrap problem - the page is shapeless

Tags: laravel, jetstrap

I created a new project and added a Jetstream.  After that i used jetstrap to swap for using bootstrap. But the page is very shapeless as an images:

[image]

[image]

how to fix this problem, if you help me i will be glad

Answer (score 1):

Try to install bootstrap on your laravel project with the followings:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap

npm install && npm run dev
```

If you don't see any changes, try to clear the browsing data and/or clear the project cache, with:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan view:clear
```